# Getting a fatal error in cuda using visual studio 2008, code, logs, attached

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging, cuda

I'm trying to write a cuda program for my school project. There seems to an error when I try to debug the project(cuda works fine, as I've run the examples and some of my previous code works fine too). I get a fatal error and the degugger points me to dgbhook.c and exits.
Here is my code, am I doing something really stupid? Screen shots and code attached here(code is a pastie, linked at the end)

[Code attached](http://pastie.org/1486487)

Answer (score 1):

Before you even get to CUDA code you have the following:

```
#define N 15
//...
int main( void ) {
    float a[N], c[N];
    int i,m=3,n=18;
    //...
    for(i=m;i<=m+n-1;i++)
        a[i] = 0;
```

So you're writing up to a[20] and b[20] which seems like a likely source of problems...

You should make sure you're building with debug symbols then step into the code to track down the source of a problem like this.